# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) How to use runRealtimeReport function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I do a call to

```
await analyticsDataClient.runRealtimeReport({
      entity: {
        propertyId: propertyId,
      },
      dateRanges: [
        {
          startDate: '2020-03-31',
          endDate: 'today',
        },
      ],
      dimensions: [
        {
          name: 'city',
        },
      ],
      metrics: [
        {
          name: 'activeUsers',
        },
      ],
    });
```

but this return the following error:

> `A property in the form 'properties/1234' where '1234' is a GA4 property Id is required`

I think it is because my object inside my `runRealtimeReport` function is wrong but I don't know how to put in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a realtime report, you need to update the request to be similar to

```
  const propertyId = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';
  const [response] = await client.runRealtimeReport({
    property: 'properties/' + propertyId,
    dimensions: [{ name: 'city', },],
    metrics: [{ name: 'activeUsers', },],
  });
```

Please replace the 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID' with your numeric property ID. This [page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/property-id) describes where to find your GA4 property ID.

Realtime reports do not need dateRanges. Realtime reports are always for the last 30 minutes for your App or Website. There is more information about creating realtime reports on this [page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-basics).

Comment: This work perfectly! Do you know how I can get users by screen_view and utm_source (campaign source)?

Comment: [These](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema) are the dimensions and metrics available in realtime. You can get the activeUsers by unifiedScreenName (screen name for Apps). The utm_source (campaign source) is not available in realtime.